# Which one is the correct way of using Python type hints with Django Models?

Tags: python, django, annotations, type-hinting

Which one of these is the correct way to use type annotations for django models?

```
from typing import TypeVar, Generic
from app.models import User

_T = TypeVar("_T", bound=User)

def func(user: Generic[_T]):
    user.name = 'John'
    user.save()
```

Or

```
from typing import Type
from app.models import User

def func(user: Type(User)):
    user.name = 'John'
    user.save()
```

Or

```
from app.models import User

def func(user: User):
    user.name = 'John'
    user.save()
```

Comment: what is `arg` supposed to do?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem well for example it can be an user instance, so it will be like `arg.user_name` or `arg.name`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `arg` should be a `MyModel` *object*, then you use:

```
from app.models import User


def func(arg: User):
    user.name = 'John'
    user.save()
```

or you can avoid importing the `MyModel` if you do not need to work with it with:

```
from typing import TYPE_CHECKING
from __future__ import annotations

if TYPE_CHECKING:
    from app.models import User


def func(arg: 'User'):
    user.name = 'John'
    user.save()
```

since importing only for type hints can easily result in cyclic import errors.

These will also accept *subclasses*, so if `MyModel` is for example an *abstract base model*, then submodels are also valid for the type hints.

Using `Generic` itself makes not much sense: this is used to define a specific type hint itself, for example a `Dict`. Furthermore `Type(MyModel)` means that you would pass the type itself, which is a subclass of `MyModel`, this thus means that you pass a reference to the `MyModel` class for example, not a `MyModel` object.

Comment: Thanks for answering, I just edited my question, I think based on what you just explained here `Type(User)` is the best option for me right?

Comment: @scaryhamid: no, that would mean that you pass `User` itself, so the `User` *class*, not a user *object*.